# Process nifi flow files present in incoming queue, all together

Tags: apache-nifi

Need help to process multiple nifi flow files together.

I am using Wait/Notify -> ExecuteScript in my flow. Wait/Notify will wait for n number of flow files to arrive and release n files together then ExecuteScript processor will check if a certain attribute has the same value in all these flow files, if not then all flow files should fail.

Below is the code snippet of groovy script

```
flowFileList = session.get(34)
if(!flowFileList.isEmpty()) {
    flowFileList.each { flowFile ->
             businessdate = flowFile.getAttribute("businessdate")
             .....
             }}
```

If all flow files have same value for businessdate then route to success otherewise fail all files.

The problem I am facing is ExecuteScript do not guarantee processing all 34 files together, sometimes it does and some time it doesn't.

Is there a way using ExecuteScript or any other processor to do so.

Could somebody please suggest how to be assured that all files should get processed together.

Comment: if you did not get from session all the files you want - just call `session.rollback()` to return all files back and wait for the next iteration.

Comment: thanks @daggett for the suggestion. can I use another wait/notify processor to wait for 34 files after executescript processor. If I receive 34 files then transfer to success otherwise transfer to fail. Would that help? Also can you please explain `session.rollback()` a bit more

Comment: `session.get(34)` gets files from incoming queue, `session.rollback()` returns all files taken from incoming queue back. your script could be triggered  when 30 files already in the incoming queue, but next 4 files are on the way, so you have to return 30 back and wait until you got 34.